# Routing not working as per expectation in React on Application Server like tomcat but it works on Node server

Tags: reactjs, tomcat, react-router, react-router-dom, react-dom

I have developed simple application in react with 2 components i.e Category and Transport . i wanted to load these components using react-dom-routes whihch i am able to do so when application is deployed on node server . But when I productionized the application and depployed in the tomcat it is not working . I have also added web.xml with below configuration in my War . Can someone please help  or let me know if I am missing anything .

On Node server I able to access component using below URL
http://localhost:3000/category
http://localhost:3000/transport

I wanted to access the component in similar way on tomcat.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';

import {BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Transport from "./Components/Transport";
import Category from "./Components/Category";


function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <BrowserRouter>
                  <Routes>
                      <Route index element={<Category/>}/>
                      <Route path="category" element={<Category/>}/>
                      <Route path="transport" element={<Transport/>}/>
                  </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>

        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?><web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" metadata-complete="false" version="3.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

    <display-name>React App </display-name>

    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/index.html</location>
    </error-page>

</web-app>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Do you get an error from the Tomcat code you didn't show?

Comment: Review [Serving apps with client-side routing](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) and this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246261/react-routing-is-able-to-handle-different-url-path-but-tomcat-returns-404-not-av/41249464#41249464).

Answer (score 0):

You have to build the react application in production mode and copy all build contents into the ROOT directory of tomcat webapps folder. Then rename `index.html` to `index.jsp`

In your `web.xml` add the below servlet mapping. This will redirect all your requests to `index.jsp`

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/index.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>index</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In case you need to redirect only specific url to the react app configure it in the `<url-pattern>`