# Add web.xml file inside React war file

Tags: reactjs, jenkins, web.xml, tomcat9

I'm trying to deploy a React app in Jenkins using Tomcat 9. Everything is working except when I try to enter an invalid route in the browser's address bar. It only displays the Tomcat 404 page instead of my custom 404 page.

The solution I found in the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) led me to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41249464/12364598). Now, the problem is how can I dynamically add a `web.xml` file inside the war file that gets built and deployed in Jenkins? I have tried adding it inside my project's `public` folder, but it only gets added inside the `build` folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the `web.xml` file is indeed getting added inside the war file when I put it inside the public folder but routes are still not working.

I tried deploying my React app using the Maven project instead of a Freestyle project and found out that the `web.xml` file is inside the `WEB-INF` folder.

I just had to create that folder inside `public` and add my `web.xml` in there.